# Código para capturar assinatura

Tags: android

Preciso saber como capturo a assinatura feita por uma pessoa em uma tela do Android para colocar em um documento (praticamente uma assinatura digital).

Answer (score 5):

Sua pergunta não está muito bem definida, mas vou tentar ajudar mesmo assim.

Não existe nada pronto no Android "oficial" para fazer isso, você precisa montar as peças, ou usar uma biblioteca de terceiros não muito conhecida. A ideia é criar um canvas (espaço na tela) onde o usuário irá desenhar livremente com o dedo ou stylus. Depois você precisará capturar a imagem formada e então fazer o que desejar com ela.

**Opção Recomendada 1: Android Signature Pad**

Uma ótima solução é a biblioteca android-signaturepad que pode ser encontrada aqui: https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad

Ela é baseada no código da Square sobre assinaturas e tem um fantástico artigo mostrando o conceito por detrás da ideia: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/smoother-signatures-be64515adb33#.aq576z753

**Opção Recomendada 2: SignatureView**

Outra ótima opção que achei foi a biblioteca **SignatureView** que pode ser encontrada em:

https://github.com/zahid-ali-shah/SignatureView

É uma solução de código aberta e completa para o que você quer. A resposta original com essa solução pode ser vista aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37314197/285678

---

Existe um outro artigo, em inglês, que pode ser útil se você não usar a opção acima, pois implementa exatamente a junção das peças conforme falei no início (embora apenas grave a imagem gerada em um arquivo, é trivial modificá-lo pra fazer o que você quiser):

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-capture-signature-using-canvas.html

Existe já uma resposta na Stack Overflow em inglês com uma implementação interessante, que fornece uma View que você pode usar para capturar as assinaturas. O código é o seguinte:

```
public class CaptureSignatureView extends View {

    private Bitmap _Bitmap;
    private Canvas _Canvas;
    private Path _Path;
    private Paint _BitmapPaint;
    private Paint _paint;
    private float _mX;
    private float _mY;
    private float TouchTolerance = 4;
    private float LineThickness = 4;

    public CaptureSignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        _Path = new Path();
        _BitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        _paint = new Paint();
        _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        _paint.setDither(true);
        _paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
        _paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        _paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        _paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        _paint.setStrokeWidth(LineThickness);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        _Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, (h > 0 ? h : ((View) this.getParent()).getHeight()), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        _Canvas = new Canvas(_Bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(_Bitmap, 0, 0, _BitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(_Path, _paint);
    }

    private void TouchStart(float x, float y) {
        _Path.reset();
        _Path.moveTo(x, y);
        _mX = x;
        _mY = y;
    }

    private void TouchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - _mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - _mY);

        if (dx >= TouchTolerance || dy >= TouchTolerance) {
            _Path.quadTo(_mX, _mY, (x + _mX) / 2, (y + _mY) / 2);
            _mX = x;
            _mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void TouchUp() {
        if (!_Path.isEmpty()) {
            _Path.lineTo(_mX, _mY);
            _Canvas.drawPath(_Path, _paint);
        } else {
            _Canvas.drawPoint(_mX, _mY, _paint);
        }

        _Path.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        super.onTouchEvent(e);
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                TouchStart(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                TouchMove(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                TouchUp();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void ClearCanvas() {
        _Canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        invalidate();
    }

    public byte[] getBytes() {
        Bitmap b = getBitmap();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        View v = (View) this.getParent();
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
        v.draw(c);

        return b;
    }
}
```

Para adicionar essa View a um LinearLayout você pode fazer:

```
LinearLayout mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
CaptureSignatureView mSig = new CaptureSignatureView(this, null);
mContent.addView(mSig, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Para pegar um array de bytes com os dados da assinatura, ou pegar um Bitmap diretamente dela use o código abaixo:

```
byte[] signature = mSig.getBytes();
Bitmap signature = mSig.getBitmap();
```

Você pode depois fazer o que quiser com essas imagens de assinaturas. Aí entra a parte menos definida da sua pergunta: em que tipo de documento você irá gravar essa assinatura? Bastará enviá-la em separado? Dependendo da sua resposta pode ser bem difícil implementar essa parte.

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo:

**DrawView.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class DrawView extends View {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
    Line currentLine;


    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(8f);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            print(canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Desenha no canvas as linhas
     * @param canvas
     */
    private void print(final Canvas canvas){
        // Deesenha todas as linha já escritas
        for(final Line l : lines){
            int max = l.pointers.size()-1;
            for(int pt =0; pt < max; pt++ ) {
                Pointer pA = l.pointers.get(pt);
                Pointer pB = l.pointers.get(pt+1);
                canvas.drawLine(pA._x, pA._y, pB._x, pB._y, paint);
            }
        }
        // Desenha a linha corrente!
        if(currentLine != null){
            int max = currentLine.pointers.size()-1;
            for(int pt =0; pt < max; pt++ ) {
                Pointer pA = currentLine.pointers.get(pt);
                Pointer pB = currentLine.pointers.get(pt+1);
                canvas.drawLine(pA._x, pA._y, pB._x, pB._y, paint);
            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap generateBitmap() {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        print(c);
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Inicia uma nova linha
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            currentLine = new Line();
            currentLine.addPointer(new Pointer(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) { // adiciona os pontos a linha
            currentLine.addPointer(new Pointer(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ){ // finaliza a linha
            lines.add(currentLine);
            currentLine = null;
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Representa um ponto
     */
    class Pointer{
        float _x, _y;
        public Pointer(float _x, float _y){
            this._x = _x;
            this._y = _y;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Representa uma linha (formado por uma lista de pontos)
     */
    class Line {
        List<Pointer> pointers = new ArrayList<>();
        public void addPointer(final Pointer p){
            pointers.add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<seu.pacote.DrawView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/assinatura"  />
```

**Activity**:

```
DrawView assinatura = DrawView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.assinatura));

final Bitmap assinaturaBitmap = assinatura.generateBitmap();
```

Comment: Legal... parece simples e parece que funciona... depois vou testar.